# How can I copy text from VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you copy text from VS Code's integrated terminal?

I'm using PowerShell. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but that produces `^c` in the terminal. Right clicking seems to paste whatever is in my clipboard.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know which version of Visual Studio Code you are using, but there has been this user setting for a while (maybe a year; I could be wrong):

```
// A set of command IDs whose keybindings will not be sent to the shell and instead always be handled by Code. This allows the use of keybindings that would normally be consumed by the shell to act the same as when the terminal is not focused, for example Ctrl + P to launch Quick Open.
  "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [

     "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
     "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
  ],
```

There are a bunch more commands in there. I am just showing the ones you are interested in. By default those copy/paste commands are already in there.

If I disable the copySelection command I get the behavior you are seeing. So you may need to either update Visual Studio Code to a newer version or make sure the above setting does appear in your user settings. As I said it is there by default for me, but perhaps something got changed for you.

[Edit in February, 2018]:

Visual Studio Code 1.20 added the setting to automatically copy to the clipboard whatever you select in the terminal. See [copy on selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_copy-on-selection).

> Copy on selection
>
> You can now automatically copy whenever you select
> text in the terminal:
>
> "**terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection**": true
>
> This
> is disabled by default.

So merely selecting any text copies it to the clipboard.

Comment: thank you, you pointed me in the right direction.  I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Code and there is a 'new' setting called "terminal.integrated.rightClickCopyPaste" which was set to true.  I just set that to false :-)

Comment: Looks promising but doesn't work for me. anymore? ..
The right-click-menu clearly shows "Copy Ctrl+C" weird.

Comment: @ewerybody Still works for me.  Did you enable the `terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection"` setting?  Then it is automatically copied if you just select the text.

Comment: No. didn't. I mean these are 2 different things, right?
But might be my best option. I'll look for issues in the tracker anyway.

Comment: Oh! Might be that's already fixed in the next version. Seems good right away in Insiders

Answer (score 23):

The solution above didn't work for me. For anybody looking for an answer: currently copy and paste in VS code terminal is bound to `ctrl+insert` and `shift+insert`.

Comment: for windows __shift+insert__ works

Answer (score 11):

To Copy a message in PowerShell visual studio just select the message and right click it, it will be copied automatically.

Comment: Well this is dumb. Why is this the default behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy VS code terminal contents using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and paste using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.
And simply you can select the terminal contents using `Shift+Ctrl+UpArrow`

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Insert to copy and to paste Ctrl + V

Answer (score 0):

For me even the selection did not work, it disappeared after finishing the selection with mouse. The way to select text was to **triple-click on the left margin** of the text in terminal window. After that, Ctrl+C was worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `Terminal: Copy Selection` command (whose command ID is `workbench.action.terminal.copySelection`) is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, which is pretty common in terminal emulator software. `workbench.action.terminal.copySelection` is included by default in `erminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell`.

You can also copy selected text by right clicking in the terminal and then using the "Copy" entry in the context menu that appears.

If you want any text you select in the integrated terminal to be copied to the clipboard by automatically, then use the `terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection` and set it to `true`.

Note that the behaviour that was being observed with right click causing pasting in the question post was related to the `terminal.integrated.rightClickCopyPaste` setting, which was superseded by the `terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior` setting in [commit 9af8e5c](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/9af8e5c2b8ddeb75b5054c5d8f482b3c4d289987).

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your terminal window and hit enter: `"terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection.set(true)"`
It worked for me.

Comment: in the VS Code integrated terminal?... what shell is this for?

Comment:  Yes, in the VS Code integrated terminal running on Windows11. This is for the Powershell.

Answer (score -1):

I've faced a similar situation. To copy from VS Code's integrated terminal without adding extra characters, select the text and then use Ctrl+Shift+C. It might be a handy workaround. Give it a shot!

Comment: my answer post already says this. what's the point in saying it again?